# How to properly infer nested and complex types in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I think sometimes Typescript does not infer properly when it comes to complex and nested types.

I need to know if it's a bug or if I'm doing wrong. And if I'm doing wrong, what is the best way to achieve inference of nested and complex types ?

I came up with this code so far:

```
// Storable type is the Object with an optional key prop
type Storable<O, Key extends string> = O & { [key in Key]?: string };
// Stored type is the Object with a required key prop
type Stored<S> = S extends Storable<infer O, infer Key extends string> ? O & { [key in Key]: string} : never

// MyObject is a standard object
type MyObject = { prop1: boolean; prop2: number; };
// MyStorableObject is a Storable MyObject
type MyStorableObject = Storable<MyObject, "id">;

// Transforms a Storable object to a Stored object
function store<T, B extends string>(object: Storable<T, B>, key: B): Stored<T> {
  return { ...object, [key]: 'generatedId' } as unknown as Stored<T>;
}
```

When I call store function, I expect stored **not** to be never type :

```
const storableObject:MyStorableObject = { prop1: true, prop2: 0 };
const stored = store(storableObject, 'id');
```

What is weird is that sometimes, it works, sometimes it doesn't. For example, with this MyObject type :

```
type MyObject = { prop1: string };
```

The stored object type is what I expect:

```
const stored: MyObject & {
    id?: string | undefined;
} & {
    id: string;
    prop1: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is what you are returning from `store`.

`Stored` takes a generic parameter that is expected to extends `Storable`, but when in `store` you are returning `Stored<T>`, you are actually returning `Stored<MyObject>`, and `MyObject` doesn't extends `Storable`, that is why `stored` is of type `never`.

So your simplest solution is to change the return type to `Stored<Storable<T, B>>`